# Flexdashboard in R with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, flexdashboard

I am trying to create an interactive dashboard in R with help of flexdashboard and shiny.

I have this table where are seven columns (translated to English): region, year, age, age2, ageMean, jobPosition and wage.

What I try to do is to create 3 dropdown filters with selectInput() for region, year and job position.

```
Bratislava I    2009    31.93   31.92   30.66   Priemyselná výroba  1510.24
Bratislava I    2009    31.93   31.92   30.66   Dodávka elektriny, plynu, pary a studeného vzduchu  1506.14
Bratislava I    2009    31.93   31.92   30.66   Dodávka vody, čistenie a odvod odpadových vôd, odpady a služby odstraňovania odpadov    911.0
```

This is what I did for now ( I am pasting whole RMarkdown, but the table I am showing below is in the script named as "dataset".

```
---
title: "Title: Bratislava"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
---

{r global, include=FALSE}
# load data in 'global' chunk so it can be shared by all users of the dashboard
library(ggplot2)
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(readxl)
library(shiny)

birthdata <- read_excel(path = "C:/Users/Dase03/Downloads/mydata.xlsx")
salarydata <- read_excel(path = "C:/Users/Dase03/Downloads/salary.xlsx")

salarydata <- salarydata %>%
    gather(jobs, wage, -1:-2) 


salarydata <- salarydata %>%
  filter(Rok > 2008 & wage > 0 & wage != "D")

birthdata <- birthdata %>%
  filter(Rok > 2008)


dataset <- left_join(birthdata, salarydata)

dataset$wage <- as.numeric(dataset$wage)

dataset$Okres <- factor(dataset$Okres)

dataset$Okres <- factor(dataset$Okres, levels = c("Bratislava I", "Bratislava II", "Bratislava III", "Bratislava IV", "Bratislava V"))

view(dataset)


Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

{r}


selectInput("x", "Choose a District", choices = unique(dataset$Okres))
selectInput("y", "Choose a Year", choices = unique(dataset$Rok))
selectInput("z", "Choose a Job", choices = unique(dataset$jobs))
```

### Outputs

#### data

```
renderPlot({
  ggplot(dataset, aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_bar()
})
```

However, I cannot make it run as it is showing me the error like this:

:1:12: unexpected symbol
1: Bratislava I
               ^

I tried to fix it, and it looked it works but the filters where not reactive. Bar chart was not changing (was not interactive so I am sure I am going wrong somewhere.

Is someone please willing to a help a bit how to make it run the dashboard?

The final output would be to use on y-axis metrics like age, age2, ageMean and wage.

Thank you a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I've done my best. I modified your code notably and your data a bit, too, to allow something to be quickly visualised.

````
[![enter code here][1]][1]

---
title: "Title: Bratislava"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}

# load data in 'global' chunk so it can be shared by all users of the dashboard
library(ggplot2)
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(readxl)
library(shiny)

# birthdata <- read_excel(path = "C:/Users/Dase03/Downloads/mydata.xlsx")
# salarydata <- read_excel(path = "C:/Users/Dase03/Downloads/salary.xlsx")
# 
# salarydata <- salarydata %>%
#     gather(jobs, wage, -1:-2) 
# 
# 
# salarydata <- salarydata %>%
#   filter(Rok > 2008 & wage > 0 & wage != "D")
# 
# birthdata <- birthdata %>%
#   filter(Rok > 2008)
# 
# 
# dataset <- left_join(birthdata, salarydata)

# Added for convenience
dataset <- read_excel(path = "joint_dataset.xlsx")

dataset$age = as.numeric(dataset$age)
dataset$wage = as.numeric(dataset$wage)

```


Column
=======================================================================

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

sliderInput("age", "Select age", min = min(dataset$age), max = max(dataset$age), value = c(min(dataset$age), max(dataset$age)))
sliderInput("wage", "Select wage", min = min(dataset$wage), max = max(dataset$wage), value = c(min(dataset$wage), max(dataset$wage)))

```


Main panel
---------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

renderPlot({
  ggplot(dataset[dataset$age >= min(input$age) & dataset$age <= max(input$age) &
                   dataset$wage >= min(input$wage) & dataset$wage <= max(input$wage),], aes(age, wage)) + geom_line()
})

```
````

.

[image]

Please notice [Flexdashboard format](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/examples.html).

Please consider [facilitating reproducibility](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For instance, column `dataset$Okres` appears out of the blue.